# Reactive Forms type mismatch with data

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, type-mismatch

I find that a lot of times there are small differences between the structure of the data I get/post to my web services and the structure of the data needed by my form.  What is the best way to handle a mismatch when using reactive forms.  Can I have some sort of getter/setter on an individual property in a form group?  What would I use for the formGroup name?

Now I am writing two transformation functions - one from my data Model to my formModel that I run onInit before I can patch the formGroup and one from my formModel to my dataModel that I run on save before I can post my data back

For example my webservices get/post this structure has seconds but the UI req is for days.

```
interface Request
{
   name:string, 
   description:string, 
   processBy: number //the number of seconds
}
```

but the UI is just going to to ask for a number of days

```
interface formModel 
{
   name:string, 
   description:string, 
   processByDays: number 
}
```

```
<input type="number" formControlName="processByDays" />
```

I had similar problems with using a custom list control that wanted an array but my data was a scalar so I had a bunch of clunky code just to wrap/unwrap a scalar value.

Comment: You shouldn't handle this conversion in your form. Handle the conversions in the service that saves your data. There's no generic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's no generic solution to this problem. However, you shouldn't handle this conversion in or around your form. Handle the conversions in the service that saves your data. You will need to do this for each field because it is a conversion specific to your business logic.

```
@Injectable() export class DataService {
  save(data: FormModel): Observable<void> {
    const {processByDays, ...saveAsIs} = data;
    const saveModel: Request = {
      ...saveAsIs,
      processBy: processByDays * 24 * 60 ** 2
    };

    return this.http.post(myURL, saveModel);
  }
}
```

You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) for readability.

```
import moment from 'moment';

const {processByDays, ...saveAsIs} = data;

const saveModel: Request = {
  ...saveAsIs,
  processBy: moment.duration(processByDays, 'days').asSeconds()
};
```